# Is it possible to delay the Revivify spell so it's activated when a character dies?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-death

The other day I was speaking with one of my players and he thought "Is there actually a way to delay a [*revivify*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/revivify) spell so it is activated when the character dies?"

I thought it could be a great idea but couldn't remember any way of delaying spells. Is there any other way to delay a spell so it activates under certain situations?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Contingency

The spell [*contingency*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contingency) covers this precisely, as long as you provide an accurate trigger.

It says:

> "Choose a spell of 5th level or lower that you can cast, has a casting
> time of 1 action, and can target you."
> "...and it affects only you, even if it can normally target others."

*Revivify* states:

> Casting Time:  1 action
>
> Range: Touch
>
> "Touch a creature that's died in the last minute."

Now you can probably set your *contingency* to trigger to be "Upon my death".  This version of *revivify* will be able to revive yourself, but can't revive others.

There may be some dispute as to whether someone is "touching" themselves when they die, but that may be grounds for a separate question.

Side note: Contingency is a level 6 Wizard spell, Revivify is a level 3 Cleric/Paladin spell.  As such, the only official ways to get this combination of spells without multiclassing inefficiently is by being a level 14+ Bard or by being a level 17+ Arcana Cleric (Sword Coast book).

Comment: You could also set your trigger to be "dead for 30 seconds" if you don't feel like returning to combat, but then you might get looted of your statuette.